Flashcard App Issue: Show Question First, Then Option to View Answer (Tkinter Python)
I’m building a flashcard app in Python using Tkinter and SQLlite3. When I try to review flashcards, the app shows both the question and answer together immediately. However, I want the app to show only the question first, and then have a button (e.g., “Show Answer”) to display the answer.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
def next_flashcard(self):
    """ Move to the next flashcard """
    if self.current_index + 1 < len(self.flashcards):
        self.current_index += 1
        self.current_flashcard = self.flashcards[self.current_index]
        self.flashcard_label.config(text=self.current_flashcard[0])  # Show question only
    else:
        self.flashcard_label.config(text="No more flashcards.")

def show_answer(self):
    """ Show the answer of the current flashcard """
    if self.current_flashcard:
        self.flashcard_label.config(text=f"Answer: {self.current_flashcard[1]}")  # Show answer separately
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "No flashcard selected!")

I’ve already added a “Show Answer” button that calls the show_answer() function, but it doesn’t work as expected. What’s happening is that the app doesn’t properly separate showing the question and answer.
How can I ensure the flashcard question displays first and then, only when the “Show Answer” button is pressed, the answer is displayed?
Any suggestions on improving the logic or fixing this issue are much appreciated! Thank you.
What I Tried:
•   I implemented the next_flashcard() function to display the flashcard’s question only and bound it to a “Next” button.
•   I created a show_answer() function, called by a “Show Answer” button, to display the answer of the current flashcard.
What I Expected:
•   When I press “Next,” only the question should appear.
•   When I press “Show Answer,” the answer for the current question should be displayed separately.
What Actually Happened:
Both the question and answer are displayed at the same time, instead of showing the question first and waiting for user input to reveal the answer.

It is better to provide a [mre] instead of just two functions as currently it is not known how you execute the two functions.
